# Translate VB that uses Active Directory in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, active-directory

I Found that code snipet that uses VB and Active Directory :

```
    Dim NbGroupe As Integer
    Dim Ldap As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://172.29.1.240:389", TxtUsager.Text & "@csnavigateurs.qc.ca", Password.Text)
    Dim Searcher As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(Ldap)
    Searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberof")
    Searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("userPrincipalName")
    Searcher.Filter = "(&(userPrincipalName=" & TxtUsager.Text & "@csnavigateurs.qc.ca))"
```

I wish to use c# for the same purpose, but i admit that this one is kind of hard to translate. Am i missing a using statement, a reference or something ? I don't see any DirectoryEntry type in my project.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/it-IT/fce9ee6f-96a8-4fed-ab3b-00c2d39a6374/directoryentry-missing-assembly-reference `add a reference to System.DirectoryService.dll`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reference the System.DirectoryServices asembly and add the corresponding using in your file.